# ngSwitchWhen doesn't work when duplicate whens are written

Tags: angular2-template, angular2-directives

I am learning angular2 using ng-book2 book and I was just playing around Built in directives.
I was reading about `ngSwitch` and I stumbled upon this feature where we can write multiple `ngSwitchWhen` with same conditions like following code:

```
   <ul [ngSwitch]="choice">
    <li *ngSwitchWhen="1">First choice</li>
    <li *ngSwitchWhen="2">Second choice</li>
    <li *ngSwitchWhen="3">Third choice</li>
    <li *ngSwitchWhen="4">Fourth choice</li>
    <li *ngSwitchWhen="2">Second choice, again</li>
    <li *ngSwitchDefault>Default choice</li> 
    </ul>
```

which will output following result:

Second Choice

Second choice, again

I wrote code as below:

```
  <div [ngSwitch]="myVar">
        <div *ngSwitchWhen="myVar==1">My Var is 1</div>
        <div *ngSwitchWhen="myVar==2">My Var is 2</div>
        <div *ngSwitchWhen="myVar==3">My Var is 3</div>
        <div *ngSwitchWhen="myVar==3">Special feature of ng Swtich</div>
        <div *ngSwitchDefault>My Var is {{myVar}}</div>
    </div>
```

which does not print output with same conditions.
I thought my code was proper but when I saw ***ngSwitchWhen="myVar==3"**
I found out my mistake.

But strangely it works properly except for repeated conditions

Is there any difference between these two conditions?

***ngSwitchWhen="2"**

***ngSwitchWhen="myVar==3"**

Which one to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ngSwitchWhen="2"
```

This expression checks the value of switchcase against the variable myVar(myVar=="6")

```
ngSwitchWhen="myVar==3"
```

Whereas this expression evaluates to myVar==(myVar==2) the value inside the parantheses return 1 if myVar is 2 and 0 if not